# How can I get video ids from this data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, youtube

First of all, I apologize if I shared anything wrong about this.
Local txt file contains html codes. Inside the html codes, Youtube video id (/watch?v=QqmdKrGiw8E etc.) data like this is in dictionary. I also need to get these video ids. I also need to parsing the video title, video description and video thumbnail. I've been trying for a couple of hours and I couldn't do it. I would love it if you could help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open("1.txt", encoding="utf8")     
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
f.close()
```

BeautifulSoup Output link: paste.ofcode.org/M9GjhGGdw3ghP7y2dcCFnE

Sorry if I broke the rules. In case of violation, I will delete the thread. Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason explaining why you are scraping instead of just using the [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) ?

Answer (score 0):

you're going to have to right click and "inspect" elements on the page to extract the ids you want

Comment: I can't access the beautifulsoup output to the elements on the page

Comment: you need to go onto the webpage that you're scraping and inspect on there, for a visual representation --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQuFl0PSoXo